# PDF READER THAT DOES NOT NEED ANOTHER PARTY

Tags: android

i am working on a project which needs to view pdf. i pretty much find it easy to view text. Is there a way i can change the below code to view pdf.

```
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            //Get the text file
            File file = new File(sdcard, textRead + ".txt");

            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }

            //Find the view by its id
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            //Set the text
            tv.setText(text);;
            }
```

Comment: is the library the main engine to view the pdf files? will i just add the library and that will be all?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not that easy. You'll need a library which'll let you decode the PDF File and then display. You can use one of these libraries to make things easy :

1. https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview
2. https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: @josedlujan, thanks but from what i could see, the application still depends on another one. what if i want it to be the reader itself?

Comment: Hey! I guess you posted on the wrong thread but you'll have to use a library. It's not as straightforward as using a TextView. Using a library does make it a lot easier and you'll be able to view pdfs inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Add Instructions to the user to install a PDF reader here, or something you want
}
```